# ScrollViewer doesn't scroll to VerticalOffset

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've got a Scrollviewer which has a StackPanel (which contain ExpanderViews)

I'm updating the ScrollViewer VerticalOffset when the ExpanderViews are expanded. However the Scrollviewer doesn't scroll up at all.

The only time the scrollviewer scrolls to a vertical offset is from within FScrollViewer_LayoutUpdated() method. (*This is tied to the LayoutUpdated event of ScrollViewer*)

Is there any way to update the VerticalOffset (or ScrollToVerticalOffset) from another method?

```
<Grid x:Name="FilterGrid" Height="696" Grid.Row="0" Background="White">
        <Grid.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection/>
        </Grid.Projection>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="FScrollViewer" toolkit:TiltEffect.SuppressTilt="True" LayoutUpdated="FScrollViewer_LayoutUpdated"
                      MouseMove="FScrollViewer_MouseMove" Width="{Binding ElementName=FilterGrid, Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=FilterGrid, Path=ActualHeight}" >
            <StackPanel Name="StackPanel" Margin="50,0,0,0" >
                <StackPanel x:Name="Header" Height="65" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent" >
                    <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderTextBlock" Text="Random text" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Black" Margin="60,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Line Width="Auto" StrokeThickness="1.5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Gray"  X1="2" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You should be able to scroll just about any time after the `ScrollViewer` is loaded. As a note, you seem to have a bunch of different ways of trying to set the `ScrollViewer`'s `Height`. In one place, you've set the `RowDefinition` to `Auto`. In another, you've attempted to bind the height to `FilterGrid`'s `ActualHeight`. This could possibly be causing issues, as the `Extent` may not be large enough when you are attempting to scroll initially.